# Do we get Gamora back?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

I noticed during the scene in *Avengers: Endgame* where, Quill and Thor are arguing over who's captain of the ship, Quill was looking at a picture of Gamora,

> assumed to be (maybe accidentally?) dusted along with all the Thanos army by the Avengers' use of the Guantlet

Is it safe to say we still don't get Gamora back?

Answer (score 27):

We *probably* get Gamora back, just not exactly the one we had since the first GOTG. This Gamora is the one who travelled with Thanos and Nebula from 2014.

The way I see it, Quill was trying to locate her in that scene, possibly to set a course for her, and this might be what GOTG vol. 3 is about; although it's unclear whether Saldana's contract has her in it: [a couple years ago](https://www.elitedaily.com/p/how-long-is-zoe-saldanas-marvel-contract-gamora-fans-are-still-hopeful-8985788), the whole cast was planned to be doing three volumes at least, but that might change.

As for Natasha, Hulk tells Captain America that he tried to bring her back along the rest but didn't manage to do it. If the Stones can't do it, then yes, Black Widow and "2018" Gamora are unlikely to come back for now. This is confirmed by a recent interview of the directors:

> **Q: Can you get the soul your sacrificed for the Soul Stone back when you return it?**
>
> A: No, the process is irreversible. Even if you have returned it to its original location, you wouldn’t be able to get the person back. In fact, it’s not really returning the Stone, more like put it back properly. The tribute soul for the Soul Stone will forever be sealed in that place, therefore Black Widow is gone forever.
>
> [*'Avengers: Endgame’ directors just explained some of the movie’s biggest mysteries*, BGR, April 30th, 2019](https://bgr.com/2019/04/30/avengers-endgame-ending-russo-brothers-on-captain-america-iron-man/)

Sure, that's beginning with the case of the Soul Stone being *returned* (not other Infinity Stone shenanigans), but then goes on to "no, never, once you're dead it's over". If that applies to Black Widow, that applies to 2018 Gamora as well.

Quill later affirms the hopelessness of trying to retrieve 'his' Gamora in *Guardians of the Galaxy 3*:

> QUILL: She [Gamora 2018] was my girlfriend, only she doesn't remember it because it wasn't her because her dad [Thanos] threw her off a magic cliff [as a sacrifice to obtain the Soul Stone] and she died. [...] And she [Gamora 2014] came back out of the past. There she is. Everyone else who died in the past stayed dead, not her. Why? Was it the magic cliff? I don't know. I'm not some freaking infinity stone scientist.
>
> NEBULA: You left out some important information, but that is the gist of it.

Comment: So, Thanos is completely removed from the universe after the Ironman gauntlet snap right? Which means the Infinity war didn't happen. Depending on what IronMan wished for we'll find out if Gamora is still alive

Comment: @StackOne [the Infinity War happened](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/99710/63559) and 2018 Gamora is not coming back, see edit incoming

Comment: @StackOne Since the past Thanos died , the Infinity war wont happen in a new timeline where Gamora might be alive. But in current Timeline Gamora is dead. There no coming back from that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes we do, but not the same Gamora. We have past Gamora from before the events of Guardian's of the Galaxy as she remained in the present timeline after the second Endgame snap.

Comment: Assuming the second Endgame snap didn't send them all back to 2014.  (we don't know; it's not discussed.)

Comment: @Harper we do know, Morgan Stark is a person that exists as per the funeral at the end of the movie, thus they didn't undo the five years that had passed. Cassie Lang is also the older version during this same scene.

Comment: Sorry, pronoun trouble, mine.  Corrected: Assuming the second Endgame (Stark) snap didn't send **Thanos'14 and his army and possibly Gamora'14** all back to 2014.  (we don't know; it wasn't discussed).

Answer (score 0):

Just as it is important to return objects (hammer) back to their source timelines, it would be equally important to return Gamora to her actual 2014 timeline. They have already caused Thanos (and friends) and Nebula to be removed from that timeline.

It might be a fair assumption to make that Gamora was sent back using the Pym Particle to her 2014 timeline. She can still meet a Peter Quill in that timeline.

Comment: No - Gamora 2014 is still in action in GoTG3! You make an interesting point, though, about the failure to 'return' Gamora along with the Infinity Stones.

Comment: She would technically be a variant as per the shoe Loki, but honestly they stopped trying to bring sense to all of this a while back.

Answer (score 0):

##### Yes, past Gamora survived the final battle in *Avengers: Endgame* and stayed in the main timeline.

In *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 3* (2023), it was revealed that the Gamora from the 2014 timeline had joined the Ravagers. This is the same Gamora in *Avengers: Endgame,* as [James Gunn confirmed on Twitter](https://twitter.com/JamesGunn/status/1656728912137977857) in response to a fan question.

[image: screenshot of James Gunn's tweet]

> […] Is GotG 3 Gamora the same Gamora that was in the Battle of Endgame?

> **James Gunn:** Yes.

Answer (score -4):

## I'll do you one better: Why is Gamora?

But in all seriousness I want to say No. Gamora will totally be in the 3rd Guardians of the Galaxy, but we won't get her back. She'll be with someone else (just google for her comic book boyfriend). She won't be the same green gal we all know and love.