# What happened to 'Gamora 2014'?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

Correct me if I'm wrong, 'Gamora 2014' was last seen after she nut-kicked Quill and questioned Nebula if he is the one (her future lover).

Following the infamous 'Ironman' snap, we saw Thanos disintegrates into dust together with his minions.

Did 'Gamora 2014' suffers the same fate as 'Thanos 2014' too?

If no, does it makes sense, timeline wise, if this 'Gamora 2014' joined the third GOTG movie?

Comment: Related: [Do we get Gamora back?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/99640/63559)

Comment: We see Quill searching for her on his map at the end scene when Thor gets on board.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Unclear.

You are correct, the last time we saw Gamora was after she so lovingly kicked Quill.
The most likely outcome is that we will learn about it in Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 3.

> But Gamora's Avengers: Endgame fate was unseen. Was she affected by Stark's snap as well? Or had her decision to side with the Avengers saved her life? She wasn't shown returning to her own time, but neither was she shown alongside the survivors in the aftermath of Thanos' defeat.
>
> ---
>
> <sub>[What Happened To Gamora In Avengers: Endgame? - ScreenRant](https://screenrant.com/avengers-endgame-gamora-2014-what-happened/)</sub>

James Gunn has already confirmed that Zoey Saldana will play a big role in Vol. 3.

> Speaking with USA Today about the new movie, Gunn revealed that while only preliminary work has begin on Guardians of the Galaxy 3, he's already begun discussing things with the franchise's stars. He and Chris Pratt have so far discussed story ideas, while Gunn has had "some pretty significant conversations" with Saldana about what is gearing up to be an equally-significant role in the upcoming movie
>
> ---
>
> <sub>[Guardians of the Galaxy 3: Gamora Will Have 'Significant' Role - ScreenRant](https://screenrant.com/guardians-galaxy-3-gamoa-role/)</sub>

So, we will be seeing her again.

Answer (score 3):

**We don't know for sure**

2014 Gamora could have snapped away alongside 2014 Thanos and his troops, or she just got out of there since she doesn’t particularly know any of these characters and isn't too close to her sister.

All we know is that in one of the last scenes of the movie, when Thor joins the Guardians, we see Quill looking for her on a screen.